# Can Scala provide type safety for array lengths?

Tags: scala

I would like to have compile time checks that array sizes are compatible.

For example the zip and transpose here are safe because a and b have the same length:

```
(a: Seq[Int]) => { val b=a.map(_+1); Seq(a,b).transpose }
```

Whereas this is unsafe because the code will die at runtime if a and b have different dimensions:

```
(a: Seq[Int], b: Seq[Int]) => Seq(a,b).transpose
```

In general if I give the dimensions of the arguments to some code, it is often possible to determine the dimensions of each variable inside the code and finally the result of the code.  Sometimes such static analysis might show up bugs immediately, sometimes the static analysis might warn about some assumptions, such as an assumption that two files have the same length,  assumptions that can and should be checked as soon as possible at runtime.  This would make the code more reliable and so I would love such checks.

I have googled and found lots of discussions but no actual implementations.

I would like this to fail at compile time:

```
Seq(Seq(1,2,3),Seq(1,2)).transpose
```

I would like this to emit a compiler warning that this will fail if a is not of dimension [2]:

```
(a: Seq[Int]) => Seq(a, Seq(1,2)).transpose
```

I would like this (or something similar) to emit no compiler warnings:

```
(a: Seq[Int]) => a.length match {
case 2 => Seq(a, Seq(1,2)).transpose
case _ => throw new Exception(s"a has the wrong dimension")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The scala standard library doesn't have anything like this, and it's pretty hard to do on your own, but you can use [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#collections-with-statically-known-sizes) which does essentially this (with plenty of caveats).

Comment: One caveat being that sizes need to be known at compile time, it seems!  That means that it cannot detect whether `(a: Seq[Int]) => Seq(a, a++a).transpose` is a good idea.

Comment: @MaxMurphy Of course it can! If `a` has length `n`, then `a ++ a` has length `n + n`. These are not necessarily equal, so you would be blocked from using `transpose` (though you'd have to *write* transpose first, it appears). Indeed, it is that fact that you *don't* know `n` that blocks the usage of `transpose`. If you knew `n = 0`, then you'd be able to use `transpose`. But, because you don't, you can't (because `n` might be `1`, and the compiler accounts for that possibility). Also note that sizes don't need to be known at compile time. Think of existentials.